# Learning about R environment variables and related concepts

Tags: r, environment-variables

I (Windows 7 user) would appreciate if someone can give a simple explanation or direct me to a good resource for learning about  R environment variables and related concepts so that I can handle them through R console or Rprofile.site . I am having hard time understanding the concept as I am trying to append different library search paths. The command `help(library)` was also not so clear in terms of what I was looking for as stated above.

I tried to search the web including stackoverflow but could not become free from confusion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [RSeek (LINK)](http://www.rseek.org/) is an excellent way to search the web for R related queries rather than a simple google search.  also check out the package `sos` [(LINK)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/sos.pdf) for another great way to search for R related searches.

Comment: For library paths check ?.libPaths

To better understand enviroments read the documentation for the proto library or Art Of R Programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-set-environment-variables_003f

?Sys.setenv ... OR  ...
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.setenv.html

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/EnvVar.html

The question about library paths might not be the same, however. See ?.libPaths

Comment: Thank you @DWin. This [link](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) was very useful.